# Fetch API error: You don't have permission to access X on this server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ups

The error: `POST https://onlinetools.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/token 403`

> You don't have permission to access https://onlinetools.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/token on this server.

I'm building a Chrome extension where in my popup.js, I make a fetch call to the UPS API to generate an OAuth token (required for tracking API usage). My call looks like the below, which matches the code in the UPS API docs example - https://developer.ups.com/api/reference#tag/OAuthClientCredentials_other:

```
const formData = { grant_type: 'client_credentials' };

const resp = await fetch(
  `https://onlinetools.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/token`,
  { method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'x-merchant-id': "<MY_CLIENT_ID>",
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(`<MY_CLIENT_ID>:<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>`)
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString()
  }
);
```

My manifest.json also has `host_permissions` which includes `https://onlinetools.ups.com/*`, which fixed the CORS issue, but no idea what this is caused by :.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong, but their sample code has a different URL to yours. 
i.e. https://wwwcie.ups.com/security/v1/oauth/token

Might be nothing?

Comment: @TonyB Yup, wwwcie is just the test server

Comment: Looks like UPS has support for their APIs: https://developer.ups.com/support?loc=en_US#tfaqs (below the FAQs are phone numbers to call). Nothing randos on the internet like us can do if it's something happening on UPS's servers...